# Pass user credentials between SharePoint web application and ASP.NET web application

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, iis, authentication

I need to integrate my sharepoint site and ASP.net site. So, First login will occur in the SharePoint site with Active Directory authentication and from there i need to traverse to ASP.Net site through a link. Now my question is whether its possible to pass my SharePoint Active Directory credentials to ASP.Net site? Will i be able to do this through a query string? Will i be able to navigate to and fro between SharePoint and ASP.Net sites.

The main point here is the user should not enter his credentials twice ( ie.. He should be authenticated automatically while navigating between two sites.)
What are the options available for me?

Do these things possible to achieve? SharePoint will be hosted using Windows SharePoint Services 3.0.

Thanks in advance,
ReplyQuote

Answer (score 3):

Is the ASP.NET site on the same network? If so, then you can use AD (Windows Auth) for authentication on the ASP.NET site just like you're using it on the SharePoint site. You don't need to pass the credentials, and you can't anyway since all you have is an authenticated identity. If you configure the ASP.NET site to require Windows Authentication, you'll be able to get the user's identity from the server variables (AUTH_USER).

See [How to: Use Windows Authentication in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647405.aspx)